# Can't resolve Promise object

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am using chained `Fetch` to get images that is relevant to articles. First, I fetch Articles' titles and then pass these to `Unsplash API` to get relevant images.

The problem is I can't get my result as `object` but only as a `promise`. I want to populate `div` with "results" `id` with object that I return from `async function` inside `cards` `variable`. I used `Timeout` as well but didn't help, still the same result.

```
async function getPrograms(params) {
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/api/?'
    url2 = 'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=XXX&content_filter=high&orientation=landscape&per_page=1&query='

    const program = await fetch(url + params).then(response => response.json());
    this.program = program;


    const cards = await program.results.map(async result => {
        // Objects that I need to populate card. Ex. title, description, date updated and etc. And also images below (for testing, only returning images):
        let images = await fetch(url2 + result.title).then(response => response.json())
        return images
        });
    this.cards = cards;


    const printAddress = async () => {
        const a = await cards;
        return a
    };
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = printAddress()
};
```

Note: I used tutorials and answers on Stack overflow but these didn't help.

Comment: You probably want to use Promise.all to await your mapped promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapped promises won't be awaited as you might think. Try [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead:

```
const cards = await Promise.all(program.results.map(async result => {
    const response = await fetch(url2 + result.title);
    return response.json();
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that I need this.program = program; and this.cards = cards; in my code? I don't know what exactly is point of these two lines. Could you please share your opinion on this too?

Comment: It's hard to tell if there's any point with those assignments without seeing the rest of the code but I can't see any obvious reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

Since within your `map()` you are again using an `async` function. `Note that Async-Functions always returns promise.` So you need to handle promise outside using `then()` `catch()` block

```
const cards = await program.results.map(async result => {
    // Objects that I need to populate card. Ex. title, description, date updated and etc. And also images below (for testing, only returning images):
    let images = await fetch(url2 + result.title).then(response => response.json())
    return images; // Here a promise is returned
    });

  cards.then(data=>{
     console.log(data);// Here you can get the data
      this.cards = data; 
  }).catch(()=>{
     console.log("Error"); 
  });
```